# Save int with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want users to be able to use the "Show Reply" feature at most 2 times per level when they purchase the "Remove Ads" item, and to continue this feature with "SharedPreferensces" when the app is closed and back on.

In the game, I ensured that "Show Answer" can be clicked at most 2 times in each level, but when you exit the level and enter back or when the game is closed and opened, this disappears and can be pressed 2 times again.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Button revealButton, askButton, doneButton;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    private int clicks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        CurrentQuestion = preferences.getInt("CurrentQuestion" + code, 0);
        currentLevelQuestion = preferences.getInt("currentLevelQuestion" + code + "_" + branch, 1);

        //AdMob Ads
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        //=======Designed for children==========//
        RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
                .toBuilder().setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
                .setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
                .build();
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
//=======================================//

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        String purchasedItem = preferences.getString("purchased", null);
        if (purchasedItem == null) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } else {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        loadRewardedAd();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //Initialize views
        questionNumberTV = findViewById(R.id.questionNumber);
        scoreTV = findViewById(R.id.score);
        questionTV = findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        LevelNumberTV = findViewById(R.id.level_number);
        revealButton = findViewById(R.id.reveal);
        askButton = findViewById(R.id.ask);
        resetButton = findViewById(R.id.reset);
        skipButton = findViewById(R.id.skip);
        doneButton = findViewById(R.id.done);
        questionImage = findViewById(R.id.questionImage);
        voiceImage = findViewById(R.id.voiceImage);
        answerGridview = findViewById(R.id.answerGridview);
        choicesGridview = findViewById(R.id.choicesGridview);

        //Scroll textView
        questionTV.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        //Initialize the new question
//        LevelNumberTV.setText(getString(R.string.level) + " " + code);
        retrieveQuestionTile();
        retrieveData();
    }

case R.id.reveal:
//                NextQuestion();
                clicks++;
                Log.e("Click+1", Integer.toString(clicks));
                Log.e("Test", "Click test break");
                if (isRunning == true) {
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    if (tickPlayer != null && tickPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        tickPlayer.stop();
                    }
                }if (purchasedItem != null && clicks >= 2){
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt("clicks", clicks);
                    editor.apply();
                    revealButton.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.purchased_warning), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (purchasedItem == null) {
                    Reveal_Answer_Dialog();
                } else {
                    currentLetter = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
                        String Letter = String.valueOf(answer[i]);
                        char compare = Letter.charAt(0);
                        user_submit_answer[currentLetter] = compare;
                        if (currentLetter + 1 < answer.length) {
                            currentLetter = currentLetter + 1;
                        }

                        //Update UI
                        recyclerAnswersAdapter = new RecyclerAnswersAdapter(user_submit_answer, this);
                        answerGridview.setAdapter(recyclerAnswersAdapter);
                        recyclerAnswersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
                break;
public void Failed_Level_Dialog() {
    wrongPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.wrong);
}

    clicks = 0;
public void Finish_Level_Dialog() {
    editor.putString("done" + "_" + code + "_" + branch, "yes");
    editor.apply();

    clicks = 0;
}
```

1. I saved the data as int with SharedPreferences, then I read the data in case: by following the click with ++.
2. I managed to inactivate the button when the button is pressed after 2 in each level, but this resets when the game comes to the homepage or when the game is closed and opened.

Comment: Please emphasize what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences are designed to persist data between app executions. However, it doesn't persist app uninstalls. That means that if a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, the data is lost. So in your case, SharedPreferences might not sound like the best solution. If you want to know if a user clicked at most 2 times in each level regardless if the app is uninstalled then you should save this information in the database.

In my opinion, the best option that you have is to save the number of clicks inside the database. Then you can perform a check each time the user clicks on the "Show Answer" option. If the number of clicks is less than two, then you should display the option, otherwise you can hide it, or display a message.

So in a Realtime Database, a structure like this will do the trick:

```
db
|
--- $uid
     |
     --- $levelId: 1
```

Where the `levelId` is the ID of a level and `1` is the number of clicks.